# Serialize vb.net class into JSON with RestSharp

Tags: json, vb.net, restsharp

I'm trying to post to a restful API using RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/)

My class looks like this:

```
Public Class CreatePostcard
    Public Property [to]() As [To]
    Public Property front() As String
     ...
Public Class [to]
    Public Property address_line1 As string
    Public Property city As String
    ...
```

My Request looks like this:

```
  Dim request = New RestRequest("postcards", Method.POST)
    Dim mm = New CreatePostcard() With {.description = "Test Desc",
        .to = New [To]() With {.name = FirstName & " " & LastName, .address_line1 = Address1, .address_line2 = Address2, .address_city = City, .address_state = State, .address_zip = Zip},
        .from = New From() With {.name = "TestFrom", .address_line1 = "123 Fake St", .address_city = "Bentonville", .address_state = "AK", .address_zip = "90210"},
        .back = BackURL, .front = FrontURL, .message = ""}

    request.AddObject(mm)

    Dim response2 As IRestResponse(Of Postcard) = client.Execute(Of Postcard)(request)
```

The API is expecting something that looks like this:

```
{
  "description": "Demo Postcard job",
  "to": {
    "address_line1": "123 Test Street",
    "address_city": "Mountain View",
    "address_state": "CA",
    "address_zip": "94041",
       },
  "from": {
  "name": "Ami Wang",
  "address_line1": "123 Test Avenue"
      },
  "message": null,
}
```

But what i'm actually sending over is:

```
{
  "to": "MyApp.To",
  "from": "MyApp.From",
  "front": "http://foo",
  "back": "http://foo",
  "message": "",
  "description": "Test"
 }
```

How do i properly seralize the object and send it to the restful API?

Comment: You need to make lists out of To and From. You are just sending a string. You need an array or list and this will reflect in you json as well. Why not use newtonsoft to serialize and deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio generates the necessary classes for the json. In your sample json, there is only one instance of tags "to" and "from"

1. Open the project Visual Studio
2. Copy the expected json
3. In Visual Studio -> Edit Menu -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes

Try below code. I used Json.Net from Nuget library for test.

```
Private Sub TestJson()

    Dim objFromJsonText As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\json.txt")
    Dim obj As Rootobject
    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(objFromJsonText)

    Dim jsonFromJsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)

End Sub

Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property [to] As [To]
    Public Property from As From
    Public Property message As Object
End Class

Public Class [To]
    Public Property address_line1 As String
    Public Property address_city As String
    Public Property address_state As String
    Public Property address_zip As String
End Class

Public Class From
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property address_line1 As String
End Class
```